# What's the "h" in `hevm` stand for?

Tags: dapptools, hevm

[Dapptools](https://dapp.tools/) has a tool called [`hevm`](https://github.com/dapphub/dapptools/tree/master/src/hevm). What's the "h" in `hevm` stand for?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Presumably [Haskell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haskell_(programming_language)), given it's and EVM implementation written in Haskell.

(See [here](https://github.com/dapphub/dapptools/tree/master/src/hevm/src/EVM) for the Haskell source code.)

Comment: ‍♂️well I feel a tad silly. t11s also corroborated this. Thank you!